# CSV-Mapper No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, fastercsv

I am using the csv-mapper gem to import a csv file. When I use the example code on in the README (http://github.com/pillowfactory/csv-mapper) in script/console it works great. However, when I create a web form and use that to upload a csv file I get the error "No such file or directory - test.csv

These are the parameters:
Parameters:

{"dump"=>{"file"=>#},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Hb+XDPUGyZQqB5H2vZnhlfXpEE9bAE16kAjTT34uQ3U="}

Here is what I have for my code in the controller:

```
def csv_import
  results = CsvMapper.import(params[:dump][:file].original_filename) do
    map_to Sale # Map to the Sale ActiveRecord class instead of the default Struct.
    after_row lambda{|row, sale| sale.save }  # Call this lambda and save each record after it's parsed.

    start_at_row 1
    [start_date, country]
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully uploaded file"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is expected because `params[:dump][:file].original_filename` only returns the file name of the uploaded CSV. The uploaded CSV should be saved to the file system first. Pass the path to the saved CSV file to `CsvMapper#import` method then it should work.

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm) for how to save uploaded files.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little late, but you should also note that CsvMapper#import takes any IO when you pass it the :type => :io option.

`results = CsvMapper.import(params[:dump][:file], :type => :io) do
...
end`

This would allow you to skip the step of saving the file prior to importing.